# DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase() Returning Encrypted Values

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, enterprise-library

I have an existing Class Library application (.Net Framework 4) that uses the `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data` DLL (v2.0.50727) and I'm getting confused on something.

There's a function in the code that writes records to a SQL table.  This function is referenced by a Windows Form Application.

The following resides in the function:

```
Dim idcConnection As IDbConnection = Nothing
Dim idtTransaction as IDbTransaction = Nothing
Dim dcInsertUpdate As DbCommand = Nothing
Dim db as Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()

dcInsertUpdate = db.GetStoredProcCommand("spInsertUpdateNote")
db.AddInParameter(dcInsertUpdate, "@NoteType", DbType.String, NoteType)
db.AddInParameter(dcInsertUpdate, "@DeptID", DbType.Int16, DeptID)
db.AddParameter(dcInsertUpdate, "@NoteID", DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.InputOutput, "@NoteID", DataRowVersion.Current, NoteID)

idcConnection = db.CreateConnection()
```

After the CreateDatabase() executes and I hover over the variable "db" the Connection String values are encrypted.

When the folllowing executes:

```
idcConnection = db.CreateConnection()
```

I get a

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

error because of the encrypted connection string. How and/or what in the application is telling it to encrypt the data? And how do I remedy that?

There is no `app.config` file in the Class Library application so is it getting what it needs from the Windows Form application that's referencing it?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The question isn't really related to the <sql> language.)

Comment: SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: What is the type of the connection string property of DB? Hover it and post a screenshot

Comment: I don't know if it's causing the problem, but I would recommend fully qualifying the stored procedure, i.e. `dcInsertUpdate = db.GetStoredProcCommand("<databasename>.<schema>.spInsertUpdateNote")`

Comment: The documentation for that method specifically states that it *"Reads service settings from the ConnectionSettings.config file"*. Do you have such a file in the program folder?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, there is no config file in the class library application.  It must be getting whatever connection it needs from the calling windows form application?  In that config file the connection string is not encrypted.

Comment: *"there is no config file in the class library application"*. There's no such thing. A library is a library and an application is an application. Only application config files are used. If you create a class library project that uses config then a config file will be generated in the project but the idea is that you are supposed to copy whatever it contains into the config file of any application that uses that library.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, correct.  So if the WinForm application has a config file with the connection strings in it and they are not encrypted, why would the connection string be encrypted when it runs the funtion in the Class Library?  I can see that when I step into the code...